# Navigator vs Routes

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I am learning Flutter and came to know about Navigator and Routes. As I read docs and got just basic understanding like they are used to navigate from one page to another, similar to intent for who knows Android. But couldn't grasp detail info and their advantages and disadvantages and most importantly when to choose one over the other?

So anyone who can help me to understand them deeply it will be great help and this will be helpful for other flutter devs too.

Thank you.

Comment: see https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/navigation

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31